# ROS Answers SE migration: Network Setup

Tags: wireless, ros-hydro, network, network-setup, multiple-machines

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two computers, both running Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Hydro.  I have a Pioneer3-DX robot which I am running with `p2os` on one computer connect to the robot by serial cable.  They are connected wirelessly through a dlink router and are able to ping each other by IP address, but not by hostname.  I am working through the ROS [Multiple Machines Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines), and am not able to get the talker/listener working.  The error which comes up is:

```
[ERROR] Unable to immediately register with master node [http://rickoFNP14eedX3:11311]: master may not be running yet.  Will keep trying.
```

Objective: Control the Pioneer3-DX wirelessly from my laptop with `teleop_keyboard`.

I am relatively new at ROS and not great at networking, so thanks for your help on this noob question.

---

**Update:**

I used `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.0.100:11311` on both machines rather than `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://rickoFNP14eedX3:11311`.  Starting `talker.py` on the onboard machine and `listener.py` on the laptop, the error no longer comes up; however, the `listener.py` on the laptop does not produce any results.

`rostopic list -v` on the laptop shows `/chatter` as a published topic with a subscriber.  However `rostopic echo /chatter` has no results from the laptop.

`rostopic list -v` on the onboard machine shows `/chatter` as a published topic with a subscriber.  `rostopic echo /chatter` shows the expected messages.

The results are the same if switch the nodes running on each computer.

---

Information of laptop:

```
jslum@rickoFNP14eedX3:~$ hostname
rickoFNP14eedX3
jslum@rickoFNP14eedX3:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 14:da:e9:bf:50:16  
          inet6 addr: fe80::16da:e9ff:febf:5016/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:220833 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15739 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:39199895 (39.1 MB)  TX bytes:2154737 (2.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:157699 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:157699 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:11060159 (11.0 MB)  TX bytes:11060159 (11.0 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:77:37:e7:db:9b  
          inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::be77:37ff:fee7:db9b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10496 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8736 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2626670 (2.6 MB)  TX bytes:1084552 (1.0 MB)
```

Information of onboard computer:

```
ecejames01@ECE521:~$ hostname
ECE521
ecejames01@ECE521:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0a:9d:e0:08:e4
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:304 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:28624 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:82259 (82.2 KB)  TX bytes:5861182 (5.8 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:7216011 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7216011 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:244946501281 (244.9 GB)  TX bytes:244946501281 (244.9 MB)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:d9:87:eb:90:fb
          inet addr:192.168.0.101  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c6d9::87ff:feb:90fb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8273 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4890 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2417399 (2.4 MB)  TX bytes:473450 (473.4 KB)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205240/network-setup/) by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 323 on 2015-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you do not have full name resolution you will probably need to set your ROS_HOSTNAME.

See the [NetworkSetup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup#Setting_a_name_explicitly) guide for more info.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-18**:
Yes...the ROS [Multiple Machine Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) refers to [Network Setup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup#Setting_a_name_explicitly), and that is how I go tthe first error mentioned above.

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-18**:
Using `ssh ECE521` or `ssh 192.168.0.101` does not work for me by the way.

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-18**:
Okay, I tried it again.

```
export ROS_IP=192.168.0.100 (or 101)
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.0.100:11311
```

worked for me.  I think the reason it did not work before is because I didn't have the right combinations.

enter code here

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-18**:
Additionally,

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.0.100 (or 101)
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.0.100:11311
```

worked as well.

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-18**:
However, setting

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=rickoFNP14eedX3 (or ECE521)
export ROS_MASTER_URI=htt[://192.168.0.100:11311
```

did not work.

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-18**:
Thanks for your help.

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-18**:
When using `rosnode machine`, only `rickoFNP14eedX3` shows up.  Should `ECE521` show up as well?